# Cannot transition state using Angular ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Im trying to get stateful routing working in an AngularJS app. My config is as follows:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('index', {          
      url: '^/',               
      templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
    })
    .state('messsage', {          
      url: '/message/:id',       
      templateUrl: 'templates/message.html'
  });

  // internal redirect to '/' as default
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
});
```

The home state renders, but when I click on a link to the second state I get an error in the console basically saying it cannot transition state:

```
Error: Could not resolve '#/message/0' from state 'index'
```

The docs / API refs I could find did not help me much.

Comment: I cannot see what's wrong, how do you try to get to the message state from index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is caused by inappropriate use of the `ui-sref` directive. There is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nhd9vgb7DVJMTcl06MIx?p=preview) showing the issue.

If, inside of the *index* state template we do create link like this:

```
<a ui-sref="#/message/0">...
```

we'll get the *`Error: Could not resolve '#/message/0' from state 'index'`*

The syntax which will work must be like this (both are the same):

```
<a href="#/message/0">...     
<a ui-sref="message({id:0})">...
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/nhd9vgb7DVJMTcl06MIx?p=preview)

Comment: I was originally doing this:
  <a ui-sref="/message/{{message.id}}"><div class="item item-image"><img ng-src="img/{{message.img}}"></div></a>
And have now changed it to:
<a ui-sref="message({{message.id}})"><div class="item item-image"><img ng-src="img/{{message.img}}"></div></a>
which seesm to be working now, thanks.

What does the :0 after the id mean in your example?

Comment: the syntax `ui-sref="message({id:0})` is the proper way how to call state and pass parameters. The `id` in `{id:0}` is a *Name* of the parameter. Why? Because there could be more like ui-sref="message({id:0, otherParam: 'abc'}). Your original attempt was exactly as I said: incorrect, because you placed *url* into `ui-sref`. Content of the `ui-sref` is the state name followed by param object inside of the braces: **`stateName({param1:value1,param2:value2})`** ... Does it make sense now?

Comment: Yes, you're passing in an object (and parameters as JSON) which makes sense, thanks.